# ServiceStack Deserialize int (unix timestamp in ms) to DateTime

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, servicestack-text

Here is a snippet of my current class: As you can see I'm deserializing to a `long` and then once it's done it calls the OnDeserialized method to finish up.  Does ServiceStack have a better way to do that?  Possibly a more direct way to so I won't need that extra method?

```
[DataMember(Name = "t")]
public long Timestamp { get; set; }
public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

[OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(TimestampLong).LocalDateTime;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried both of the methods you suggested but neither worked for me.  Here's more code so hopefully you can identify my mistake:

*MyClass*

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    //... (other members working fine)
    
    [DataMember(Name = "t")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

*Deserializing (Unit Test)*

```
var message = "[{...(other members working fine)...\"t\":1612446479354}]";
using var config = JsConfig.With(new Config {DateHandler = DateHandler.UnixTime});
//var myClass = message.FromJson<MyClass[]>();
var myClass = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyClass[]>(message);

Assert.IsTrue(ticks[0].Timestamp == DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1612446479354).LocalDateTime);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just make `TimestampLong` be a surrogate property, converting and returning the value of `Timestamp`, like so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZeZbyz ?

Comment: Incidentally, the problem with the code shown in the answer below, and in your updated question, is that [`DateHandler.UnixTimeMs`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/379c4ffb525945b799e4350098020d863ff8e61c/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L1058) should be used instead of `DateHandler.UnixTime`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HVM9c1

Comment: Should I add those comments as an answer?

Comment: @dbc Can you/are you ok with just editing mythz's answer (or I can) rather than posting an almost identical one? (I think that would be less confusing for anyone else who sees this question later but if you want the points I'm ok with that too)

Comment: You or I could edit the other answer to use `DateHandler.UnixTimeMs` but the suggestion to use a surrogate property would be a second answer, if you're interested in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can specify a scoped configuration to tell the serializer the Date Times are sent as unix times, e.g:

```
using var config = JsConfig.With(new Config { DateHandler = DateHandler.UnixTimeMs });
var dto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyType1>(json);
```

If all DateTime's are sent as Unix Times you can specify a global configuration on Startup with:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    DateHandler = DateHandler.UnixTimeMs
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working.  (please see the update in my question)

Comment: Just noticed my answer was updated to use `UnixTimeMs`, note your question should specify you want Unix Time in **ms**, [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

Comment: When I asked the question I didn't know I needed to specify. (my ignorance is showing) I have updated the question for future viewers. Thanks for pointing that out.